# Removing complete node from the XML stored in string type variable using C# before loading in XMLDocument

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, .net-2.0, linq-to-xml

I have got the XML below, which is stored in string type variable, and I am using .NET 2.0:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<tcm:ListPublications xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0" Managed="1">
    <tcm:Item ID="tcm:0-437-1" Title="05 Main Australia Web Site (English)"/>
    <tcm:Item ID="tcm:0-445-1" Title="06 Internal India Web Site (English)"/>
    <tcm:Item ID="tcm:0-437-1" Title="07 EKTA Australia Web Site (English)"/>
    <tcm:Item ID="tcm:0-445-1" Title="07 EKTA India Web Site (English)"/>
    <tcm:Item ID="tcm:0-414-1" Title="07 Bahrain web Site (Arabic)"/>
    <tcm:Item ID="tcm:0-272-1" Title="07 USA web Site (US English)"/>
    <tcm:Item ID="tcm:0-279-1" Title="08 Bahrain web Site (English)"/>
    <tcm:Item ID="tcm:0-392-1" Title="08 Belgium web Site (French)"/>
    <tcm:Item ID="tcm:0-321-1" Title="08 Brazil web Site (English)"/>
</tcm:ListPublications>
```

Now, before loading it to my XMLDocument, I want to load only those "Item" nodes which are having Title="07" and does not contain "EKTA" in the title.

And the C# code to do this is given below:

```
//Creating the object of PublicatinBL class.
PublicationBL pubBL = new PublicationBL();

//All publications list XML.
//Here I am getting the whole XML as shown above.
string pubListXML = pubBL.getAllPublicationListXML(); 

XmlDocument xDocument = new XmlDocument();

//Loading the publication list XML.
//Here before loading the XML, I want to modify it as required above.
xDocument.LoadXml(pubListXML);
```

Comment: What's wrong with removing nodes from `xDocument`? To remove nodes, you're going to have to load the XML one way or another anyway. It's easy to select targets with an xpath like `//tcm:Item[contains(@title,'07')][!contains(@title,'EKTA')]`.

Comment: You could also run a regex on the string to replace strings that don't match with an empty string.

Comment: Hi Anton, my complete XML is in String variable, can you please let me know how can use XPath in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [LINQ to XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query#LINQ_to_XML):

```
var xdocument = XDocument.Parse(xml);

var nodes = xdocument.Descendants(XName.Get("Item", "http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0"))
    .Where(arg => arg.Attribute("Title").Value.Contains("07") && !arg.Attribute("Title").Value.Contains("EKTA"))
    .ToList();
```

Or with LINQ syntax:

```
var nodes = (
    from node in xdocument.Descendants(XName.Get("Item", "http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0"))
    let titleAttribute = node.Attribute("Title").Value
    where titleAttribute.Contains("07") && !titleAttribute.Contains("EKTA")
    select node)
    .ToList();
```

**[Update] After .NET 2 was specified in the question.**

In .NET 2 you can use XPath:

```
XmlNamespaceManager xmlnsManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDocument.NameTable);
xmlnsManager.AddNamespace("tcm", "http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0");
XmlNodeList nodes = xmlDocument.SelectNodes(
    "//tcm:ListPublications//tcm:Item[contains(@Title,'07') and not(contains(@Title,'EKTA'))]",
    xmlnsManager);
```

Comment: THanks @Alex, but I am using .NET 2.0 which does not have "VAR" and "LINQ", please suggest!!